# ncurses mvaddch() cursor movement a possible bug?

Tags: c, ncurses, cursor-position

Code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();


    mvprintw(0, 0, curses_version());
    mvprintw(1, 0, "Hello World");
    mvaddch(2, 0, mvinch(1, 4));                 // Why doesn't this work?

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ncurses 5.9.20130608  
Hello World
```

with pointer blinking (waiting for `getch` ) just after `o` of `Hello`.

Question:
As in C, arguments passed to a function are evaluated first before calling that function, `mvinch()` will be called first and when it'll return the character `o` the call to `mvaddch()` will be made.
But then why character `o` is not printed on line 2 (just below `Hello World`)? Instead `mvaddch` prints `o` at current cursor position (thanks to `winch` which is 1,4). Here `mvaddch()` behaves just like `addch` paying no respect to the `mv` prefix and the explicit movement coordinates given to it. Why?

Is this a possible bug in mvaddch() or am I missing something?

EDIT:
`$ uname -a`
`Linux Titanic 3.11.0-26-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What platform are you on? I get the 'o' below the 'H' in "Hello". As a side note, be careful with printing strings with `mvprintw()` like that. You're in trouble if the string happens to contain format specifiers (e.g., `%s`). It's safer to use `mvaddstr()` for fixed strings.

Comment: @Ulfalizer - Here since the string is not user generated as in `mvprintw(x, y, str)` rather hard coded, I think there's no worry in this `mvprintw` form. As for system details I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Yeah, it's unlikely to break here. Just something worth being aware of. What terminal are you using?

Comment: @Ulfalizer - Sure thing! I am using xterm

Comment: I had forgotten to include *ncurses.h*. Sorry about that. Found the real issue now.

Comment: BTW, the reason it works when you don't include the header is probably that ncurses exports "real" versions of those functions too, which get used instead.

Comment: for greater portability, include `<curses.h>`, *not* `<ncurses.h>`. Use the standard, do not enforce a particular implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `mvaddch()` happens to be implemented as a macro. A call like

```
mvaddch(2, 0, foo);
```

expands to the following (with some parentheses removed):

```
wmove(stdscr, 2, 0) == -1 ? -1 : waddch(stdscr, foo);
```

You can check this using e.g. `gcc -E`.

As can be seen above, `foo` will be evaluated after `wmove()`, meaning any cursor position set by `foo` will take precedence.

To work around it, you could explicitly save the result from `mvinch()` to a `chtype` variable and use that when calling `mvaddch()`.

(`mvinch()` seems to be a macro as well, implemented in terms of `wmove()` and `winch()`.)

Comment: So the takeaway seems to never to use the movement functions as argument of other movement function as most probably the movement functions are implemented as macros so the order of cursor movement might not be as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @rootkea: Or more generally to watch out for unexpected evaluation ordering when macros might be involved. Another common macro-related issue is arguments getting evaluated twice (as in a classical C `min/max` macro implementation). The most general advice is to keep arguments simple and free of side effects. Suppressing the macro version with parentheses works too, if you know there's a corresponding function.

Comment: "Suppressing the macro version with parentheses to use the corresponding function"  Is that a ncurses specific feature because it doesn't seem to work in plain C code? Any reference link is welcomed.

Comment: @rootkea: It's plain C. A function-like macro is only expanded if there's an opening parenthesis directly after the name. ("Directly" as in nothing but whitespace between the name and the opening paren.) See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html for example.

Comment: Note that there must be a real function to call if you suppress the macro though :). It's a pretty common requirement in standards that there must be a "real" function too for many things that are allowed to be implemented as macros.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `mvaddch` and `mvinch` move the same cursor position, and that `mvinch` is evaluated later.

The result is that the "o" is added back into the cell from which it was read, and there is no visible change.

Both `mvaddch` and `mvinch` are normally macros. You can change this by #undef'ing either, or putting the macros names in parentheses, e.g.,

```
(mvaddch)(2, 0, (mvinch)(1, 4));
```

Because the *move* is evaluated outside the functions, the order of evaluation is determined by the macro.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand. `mvinch` ought to evaluate first since it's an argument to `mvaddch` right? And then when `mvaddch` will get called I see no problem in manipulating the common current cursor coordinate variables by `mvaddch` irrespective of what other previously called cursor position manipulating functions did.